# Backgrid.js with Backbone-pageable, how set inital page number, sort and sort type in client mode paginator?

Tags: backbone.js, backgrid

When backgrid paginator is in client mode, I unable to set initial page number, sort column and order type.

I simply created my grid following example in backgrid-paginator-master package then set initial page, order column and order type in following way:

```
var Profiles = Backbone.PageableCollection.extend({
    model: ProfileModel,
    mode: "client",
    url: JSONUrl,
    state: {
        firstPage:1,
        pageSize:10,
        currentPage:3,
        sortKey:"idProfile",
        order:1 
    }
});
```

The data in the grid are shown correctly, that is, the page shown is the number 3 and also the sort column is right but the paginator is not updated according to page passed to currentPage property of PageableCollection: is always shown as the current page to be the first.

Note that everything works fine when click on the different page number in paginator but if I want to go directly on the page 3 at first page loading, the paginator is not shown correctly.

I have reproduced the glitch here:`http://85.94.202.20//backgridtest/index.php`

and you can call the various pages by passing the value directly in the URL like this:`http://85.94.202.20/backgridtest/index.php?page=3`

As you can see the data in the grid change, but the paginator does not refresh the active page according set with: `currentPage:[page number]`

There is another way to force the paginator on the specific page, sort and sort type at first page loading?

I'm using latest versions of the various components:

- underscore.js -> 1.5.2
- backbone.js -> 1.0.0
- backbone-pageable.js -> 1.4.1
- lunr.js -> 0.4.3
- backgrid.js -> master version
- backgrid-paginator -> master version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shouldn't be a problem anymore as of 0.3.5. Update your libraries and try again.

Comment: Thak you Jimmy. I have updated to the latest production version (0.3.5) and now it works.

I edit your example: [Backbone paginator client mode example](http://backbone-paginator.github.io/backbone.paginator/examples/client-mode.html) and I added the following code snippet:

`territories.fetch().done(`
  `function () {`
    `territories.setSorting("pop", 1);`
    `territories.fullCollection.sort();`
    `territories.getPage(2);`
  `});`